# TABULATOR : link formatter : urlField do not parse the value with nestedSeperator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm trying to use the link formatter with json data where the url is stored in a sub object of my data. The `<a>` created by tabulator has an `href` attribute set on `undefined`. It should have the provided url.

It looks like the urlField from the formatterParams is not parsed with `nestedSeperator` even the default one `.`. Is it a bug ?

The data example:

```js
let data = [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "PostgreSQL 14.x",
                    "constructeur_id": 22,
                    "domaine_id": 90,
                    "show": "https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/dummy.html",
                    "domaine": {
                        "id": 90,
                        "name": "SGBD",
                        "show": "https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/dummy.html"
                    },
                    "constructeur": {
                        "id": 22,
                        "name": "POSTGRESQL",
                        "show": "https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/dummy.html"
                    }
                }
            ]
```

tabulator params :

```js
 table = new Tabulator("#table", {
                data:data,
                // Set column definitions
                columns: [
                    {
                        title: "Domaine",
                        field: "name",
                        formatter: "link",
                        formatterParams: {
                            labelField: "domaine.name",
                            urlField: "domaine.show",  // DO NOT WORK AND I DON'T KNOW WHY, MAY BE urlField DO NOT PARSED THE VALUE WITH THE SEPARATOR (HERE THE DEFAULT ONE .) 
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Constructeur",
                        field: "name",
                        formatter: "link",
                        formatterParams: {
                            labelField: "constructeur.name",
                            url: function (cell) {
                                return cell.getData().constructeur.show;
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Nom du modèle",
                        field: "name",
                        formatter: "link",
                        formatterParams: {
                            labelField: "name",
                            urlField: "show",
                        },
                    }
                ],
            });
```

More details, and fiddle provided below.

I give you a fiddle to explain more in details the different case, which works and which don't.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmevgdL4/)

We have 3 different cases (one for each column) to deal with url here :

1. DOMAINE : we try to use 'urlField' property of `formatterParams` using `"domaine.show"` as value. It should look for `show` property of the domaine sub object. But it doesn't work... We have undefined instead
2. CONSTRUCTEUR : We use `url` property of `formatterParams` and provide a function that fetch manually the url (here on constructeur.show). It works
3. NAME : We use `urlField` property of `formatterParams` and provide a value that point to a direct property of the data object (not through a sub object). It works

To show that it really does not parse the ulrField value i add a second data object, but this time with a 'domaine.show' value (not a sub object domaine with a 'show' property) and this time it works.

To those who have the same problems as me, the two solutions i had found are :

- Move the property use in `urlField` to the main object, not a sub one.
- Use the `url` property and provide manually through a function the value (ex : function (cell) { return cell.getData().constructeur.show;})